# Player ReSpawn Logic Unity Multiplayer

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was learning multiplayer game implementation through Unity Multiplayer system.
So I come across this really good tutorials written for beginners:
[Introduction to a Simple Multiplayer Example](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/introduction-simple-multiplayer-example?playlist=29690)

From this tutorial, I can't able to understand this page content:
[Death and Respawning](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/death-and-respawning?playlist=29690)

Through this code, in tutorial they are talking about our player will respawn (player will transform at 0 position and health will be 100) and player can start fighting again.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

public class Health : NetworkBehaviour {

public const int maxHealth = 100;

[SyncVar(hook = "OnChangeHealth")]
public int currentHealth = maxHealth;

public RectTransform healthBar;

public void TakeDamage(int amount)
{
    if (!isServer)
        return;

    currentHealth -= amount;
    if (currentHealth <= 0)
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;

        // called on the Server, but invoked on the Clients
        RpcRespawn();
    }
}

void OnChangeHealth (int currentHealth )
{
    healthBar.sizeDelta = new Vector2(currentHealth , healthBar.sizeDelta.y);
}

[ClientRpc]
void RpcRespawn()
{
    if (isLocalPlayer)
    {
        // move back to zero location
        transform.position = Vector3.zero;
    }
}
}
```

As per my thinking -> All clients are executing ClientRPC so all devices local players will move at the spawn position and health get full.
As per this tutorial -> only own player's spawn position and health get updated.

So why this thing is happening that I can't able to understand?
Actually RPC get called on all clients then all clients should require to move at start position and get full health.
Please give me some explanation in this.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on this image, you need to think that network systems aren't a "shared" room, they actually works as copying everything about the others on your own room.
[image]
Knowing that, now you can understand that if you send the Rpc from your Player 1, that Rpc will be executed on your Player1, and the Player 1- Copy on Player's 2 room.

Cause as you can read on the docs, the [ClientRpc] attribute:

> is an attribute that can be put on methods of NetworkBehaviour
> classes to allow them to be invoked on clients from a server.

So as Player 1 room is the host (server+client) an Player 2 is client, it will be executed on 2 room's, but evaluated on the first one.

**Edit: That means that when, for example, Player 1 will die, it will call the RPC function, and (cause it's an RPC) his copy (Player1-Copy) on Room 2, will do the same.**

Comment: as per my understanding In my device my player is local player for the game and in my friend's device his player is local player for that game.... So we both have our own local player in each device, what do you think?

Comment: that's true, there is only one local player per device, which is the problem?

Comment: Then as per above example, all player will reach at spawn position :) Is this true ?? rather than only dead player require to respawn...

Comment: No, the RPC will be called on the Player object that calls the RPC, and his copy on the other room. So will only change position of the player that dies.

Comment: I think your last last running correctly and I am understanding as well - can you please update your answer regarding this because my question's main target was this only :)

Comment: @Siddharth Updated Siddharth, if that answer helps you, mark it, to mark the post as solved pleaes ^^

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, respawnprefab has to be instantiated on ServerRpc and the actual respawning logic (changing the transform of the player) should be given in ClientRpc.

```
private void Die()
{
    isDead = true;

    //Disable Components
    for (int i = 0; i < disableOnDeath.Length; i++)
    {
        disableOnDeath[i].enabled = false;
    }

    Collider _col = GetComponent<Collider>();
    if (_col != null)
    {
        _col.enabled = false;
    }

    Debug.Log(transform.name + " is Dead");

    //call respawn method
    StartCoroutine(Respawn(transform.name));
}

private IEnumerator Respawn(string _playerID)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(GameManager.instance.matchSettings.respawnDelay);
    SpawningServerRpc(_playerID);
   
}

[ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
void SpawningServerRpc(string _playerID)
{
    Transform spawnedPointTransform = Instantiate(spawnPoint);
    spawnedPointTransform.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn(true);
    SpawnClientRpc(_playerID);   
}

[ClientRpc]
void SpawnClientRpc(string _playerID)
{
    Player _player = GameManager.GetPlayer(_playerID);
    Debug.Log("The player who dies is:" + _player.transform.name);
    _player.transform.position = spawnPoint.position;
    Debug.Log("I am Respawned" + _player.name + "Position:" + _player.transform.position);
    SetDefaults();
}
```

Hope this helps you. Cheers